# Stuck on a c++ lucky seven game program

Tags: c++, dice

My Basic Algorithm:

Ask for input money amount; Rolls two 6-sided dice; if they add up to 7, add 4 to money amount; else, subtract 1 from money amount; loop until `moneyamount<0`; loop game user says n when prompted to play again.

```
/*
*File: hw3
*Author: Nathaniel Goodhue
*
*Created on: 9/15/15
*Description: Game of lucky sevens
*                
*/

#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   srand (time(NULL));
   double moneyAmount;
   int winValue = 7;
   int numRolls = 0;
   char playAgain = 'y';

   while(playAgain == 'y')
   {
      cout<<"Enter the amount of money you are playing with: $";
      cin>>moneyAmount;

      while(moneyAmount>0)
      {
         int roll1= (rand()%6)+1;
         int roll2 = (rand()%6)+1;

         if(roll1+roll2 == winValue)
         {
            moneyAmount+=4;
             numRolls++;
         }

         else
         {
            moneyAmount-=1;
            numRolls++;
         }
      }
      cout<<"It took "<<numRolls<<" roll(s) to lose all of your money"<<endl;
      // cout<<"Your maximum amount of money was $" <<maxAmount<<" after "<<maxRolls<<" roll(s)"<<endl;
      cout<<"Play again? y/n"<<endl;
      cin>>playAgain;
      if(playAgain == 'y')
      {
         cout<<"Enter the amount of money you are playing with: $";
         cin>>moneyAmount;
         numRolls = 0;

      }

      else 
      {
         break;
      }
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Above is my current code. It works as intended. What I am stuck on is that I need to be able to implement this line of code right after money drops below 0:

```
  cout<<"Your maximum amount of money was $" <<maxAmount<<" after "<<maxRolls<<" roll(s)"<<endl;
```

I need to find out when there was the most money and after how many rolls that it appeared. The `maxAmount` variable would be the max amount of money achieved, and the `maxRolls` variable would be the number of rolls when `maxAmount` was reached.

Comment: You have numRoles.  All you need to do is store the money for a role if it is higher than the current max.  I would tade a look at std::max as it does the logic for you.  You will need to either fix where you declare numRoles or resetit btw

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty simple to add to your code.  What you can do is check if the amount of money they have is greater than the max amount of money.  If it is then set max to current and record the number of turns it took to get that value.

```
int maxAmount = moneyAmount, maxRolls = 0;

while(moneyAmount > 0)
{
    int roll1 = (rand() % 6) + 1;
    int roll2 = (rand() % 6) + 1;
    numRolls++;

    if(roll1 + roll2 == winValue)
        moneyAmount += 4;
    else
        moneyAmount -= 1;

    if (moneyAmount > maxAmount)
    {
        // the current amount of money is greater than the max so set max to current and get the number of rolls
        maxAmount = moneyAmount;
        maxRolls  = numRolls;
    }
}
```

Comment: NathanOliver, Thank you! I knew it was a simple addition, just had a brain fart trying to figure out how exactly it would look in code. Really appreciate the assistance. Have a great day!